# Count group by in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

My current select statement:

```
return User::select('id', 'created_at')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get()
                    ->groupBy(function($date) {
                        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y m d');
                    });
```

This currently returns

```
2015 07 28: [
{
id: 935,
created_at: "2015-07-28 23:00:20"
}
],

2015 07 27: [
{
id: 926,
created_at: "2015-07-27 17:13:58"
},
{
id: 925,
created_at: "2015-07-27 15:00:36"
},
{
id: 924,
created_at: "2015-07-27 13:37:00"
}
]
```

What I just want is:

```
Date | Users
-----+------
7/28 | 1
7/27 | 3
```

Comment: use `count(id)` instead of id in your select

Comment: This counts every row in the `users` table. I want to be able to count the users / per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to group by in query level as below, and it will be fast, give it a try :)

```
return User::select(\DB::raw('id, count(id) numberOfUsers, DATE(created_at) dateOnly, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m/%d" ) displayDate'))
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('dateOnly')
                ->get();
```

`DATE(created_at) dateOnly` will select the date from the datetime filed as `dateOnly`,

`DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m/%d" ) displayDate` this will format the date to display like `month/date` => `04/07` as `displayDate`,

`count(id) numberOfUsers` select the number of users as `numberOfUsers` in each group after group by `dateOnly`.

then you can use these date to display as you want,

EX:

**$users => results get from the above query**

```
    echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Date</td>";
    echo "<td>Users</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $user->displayDate ."</td>"; // prints the formatted date.
        echo "<td>". $user->numberOfUsers ."</td>"; // prints the users count.
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

here is the [date formats](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) available in `mysql`